# How to use RecyclerView onCreate

Tags: java, android, layout-inflater, android-recyclerview

I am trying to populate a RecyclerView with a group of contacts from a SQLite db. Everything I read about doing this from the onCreate says to do it like this

```js
public class Contacts extends Activity {
 
 private RecyclerView rView;
 private NewAdapter adapter;
 
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.contacts_main);
  
  rView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.r_list);
  adapter = new NewAdapter(Contacts.this, DBDatabaseAdapter.getContactData());
  rView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
  rView.setAdapter(adapter);
      }
  }
```

But it gives me an error

03-25 22:17:24.505: E/AndroidRuntime(16011): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{edu.ecpi.myappv3/edu.ecpi.myappv3.Contacts}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

Other tutorials handle it like this

```js
public View listCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
     View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_contact, container, false);
     rView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.r_list);
     adapter = new NewAdapter(Contacts.this, DBDatabaseAdapter.getContactData());
     rView.setAdapter(adapter);
     
     return layout;
    }
```

and it has an inflater. I want to use the first way. Can anyone help.
Here are is my relavent code:

```js
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class NewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

 private final LayoutInflater inflater;
 private Contact[] contact;
 
 public NewAdapter (Context context, Contact[] contact)
 {
  inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
  this.contact=contact;
  
 }
 @Override
 public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_contact, parent, false);
  MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
  return holder;
 }
 @Override
 public int getItemCount() {
  
  return contact.length;
 }

 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
  Contact current = contact[position];
  holder.name.setText(current._name);
  holder.address.setText(current._address);
  
 }


 class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
 {
  TextView name;
  TextView address;
  public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
   
   super(itemView);
   name=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.contactlayout_name);
   address= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.contactlayout_address);
   
  }
  
 }

 
}
```

```js
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/contact_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/r_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

```
Here is the xml for the recycled object.
```

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/contactlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contactlayout_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contactlayout_address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: referenced appcompat??

Comment: Unrelated, but you can inflate the viewholder layouts this way: View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                       R.layout.custom_contact, parent, false);

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to add RecyclerView to your build dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
```

Source: https://knowledgecollisions.wordpress.com/2016/03/29/using-recyclerview-and-cardview-in-your-android-app/